# Emscripten canvas + jQuery - toggle focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, emscripten

I have an HTML page roughly divided 30% - 70% into two vertical columns. The left column contains a chat feed (handled via Node and Socket.io), and the right column contains an emscripten-generated `canvas` (with the ID of `canvas`). The canvas contains a basic 3D world that the user can navigate using standard first-person controls (WASD for movement, mouse to 'look').

By default, the canvas swallows all keyboard events. I've fixed this with the following code in the canvas initialisation procedure:

```
Module.preRun.push(function () {
    ENV.SDL_EMSCRIPTEN_KEYBOARD_ELEMENT = "#canvas";
});
```

This allow me to manually focus on the chat box, type a message, and submit it.

The issue I'm running into is that once the chat message has been submitted, I try and return focus to the canvas with the following code (to allow the players to navigate the 3d world with WASD):

```
 $('#canvas').focus();
```

This nominally returns focus to the canvas, but mouse and keyboard movement does not work. Oddly, clicking off the tab/browser window and then into the canvas seems to work - focus is returned to the canvas, and I can navigate once more. Manually calling `$(window).blur().focus()` doesn't do the trick.

Does anyone know how to force focus back to the canvas once a chat message has been sent?

**-- UPDATE --**

I've added a text input field (with the ID of `hiddenField`) behind the canvas and I'm using the preRun function to assign key events for the canvas to that field (canvas wasn't working consistently for some reason).

This works fine *until* the user clicks off the canvas - for example, into the chat field - whereupon the canvas stops responding to any keyboard or mouse input, even though I'm triggering focus back onto the `hiddenField` (and can see that it's getting it).

It seems that doing *anything* on the page conflicts with emscripten's focussing behaviour (tied to the window object, I believe) and prevents the canvas from regaining focus.

Surely there's some way of aloowing the emscripten canvas to live alongside other HTML elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best approach I've been able to find to this - indeed, the only way to get the separate aspects of the application (chat & 3D world) working correctly - has been to embed the emscripten canvas in an `iframe` and use cross-frame function calls when necessary to trigger actions.

```
Page
    - chat
    - iframe
        -- emscripten-generated page
```

It's not my first choice of solution, but it's the only one I've managed to get working.

Answer (score 6):

You need to make `canvas` object focusable by adding `tabindex="0"` attribute.

Then it should be possible to trigger the focus event properly:

```
document.querySelector("#canvas").focus()
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

View full demo via [CodePen](https://codepen.io/shagamemnon0/pres/wqLdqm?editors=0011) (includes links to `.js` resources)

**Structure:**

```
Page
    - emscripten-generated-page
       - loop
    - chat
    - script to handle global key input handlers
```

You **must** set `tabindex` on the canvas element (as noted by [luke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1905073/luke) and [described on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onfocus)), attach global event listeners via JavaScript’s built-in `Document` interface and then call `.triggerHandler()` to ensure that canvas returns to it's default state, governed by `click`:

```
var chatInputField = $("#message-input");
var canvas = $("#canvas");


canvas.on("click", function(e){
  return document.addEventListener("keyup", game.toggleKeys);
});

chatInputField.on("focusin", function(e) {
    $('#canvas').attr('tabindex', 0);
    return document.removeEventListener("keyup", game.toggleKeys, false);
});

chatInputField.on("focusout", function(e) {
    $("#canvas").triggerHandler('click');
    chatInputField.attr('tabindex', 0);
});
```

I’ve tested this, it works. Here’s my app.js file for managing key input (see line 297).

https://gist.github.com/shagamemnon/585df8dd215a949b839f8b02199af31b

A caveat: you *must* explicitly define the behavior of the the `tab` key inside the game canvas.